# access php variable into external javascript file

Tags: javascript, php

I get var value into php code. I want to access it into included test.js file.

```
<?php
 session_start();
$var=$_SESSION['my_id'];  // I want to access $var into test.js included below
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<!-- AddThis Smart Layers END -->
</head>
<input type="submit" onclick="func();">  Button </input> //This function call test.js
<body>
```

How can I access $var into test.js?

Comment: Are you in control of the JS file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it as a parameter:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="func('<?php echo $var; ?>');">
```

in test.js:

```
function func(param){
   console.log(param); // contents of $var
}
```

Or set it globally:

```
<script>
   var param = "<?php echo $var; ?>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this-

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $var=$_SESSION['my_id']; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var my_id_j = '<?php echo $var; ?>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<!-- AddThis Smart Layers END -->
</head>
<input type="submit" onclick="func();">  Button </input> //This function call test.js
<body>
```

Here I have added following line before including the test.js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var my_id_j = '<?php echo $var; ?>';
</script>
```

In this the variable my_id_j is global variable, will be accessible in test.js

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of handling this scenario:

## Usual Case: Passing it as an argument in functions

Example:

```
 <?php $myvar = 'Hello'; ?>
   // other code
 <script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js"></script>

   // and when you are about to call the function:
 <input type="submit" onclick="func('<?php print $myvar; ?>');">
```

### Rather Special Case: Loading the JS file and replacing a special value.

In the past, there have been cases that I couldn't do the above. I can't recall of any easy example at the moment, but what I have done was this:

```
 <?php
   $my_var = 'Hello';
   $my_script = file_get_contents('path/to/file.js');
   $my_script = str_replace('%SPECIAL_VALUE%', $my_var, $my_script);

   print '<script type="text/javascript">'.$my_script.'</script>';
 ?>
```

And then I was able to simplify my Javascript by doind anything like:

```
 var myvar = '%SPECIAL_VALUE%';

 alert('%SPECIAL_VALUE%');
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass the variable to javascript first:

```php
<script type="text/javascript">
    var variable = "<?=$_SESSION['my_id'];?>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

You can then use it within `test.js` either as `variable` or `window.variable`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$var=$_SESSION['my_id'];  // I want to access $var into test.js included below
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript>
var myJsVar = "<?php echo $var;?>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<!-- AddThis Smart Layers END -->
</head>
<input type="submit" onclick="func();">  Button </input> //This function call test.js
<body>
```

Now you can access the var throught myJsVar