# Get PHP variable in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a PHP file on my server which is counting the number of files in a directory. I would like to get the number of files ($fileCount) in my Javascript file.

**numberOfImages.php**:

```
<?php
$dir = "/my/directory/";
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$fileCount = iterator_count($fi);
echo $fileCount; 

?>
```

**main.js** **(EXTERNAL JS FILE)**
I don't have any code to do with my php file in my JS file yet. I would like to get the variable from my PHP file(http://www.website/numberOfImages.php) and use it (alert it) in my **external** JS file.

I'm willing to use AJAX.

Comment: Are you looking for ajax syntax : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: don't know what is your question.you should follow a tutorial.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515723/access-php-variable-into-external-javascript-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access PHP var from external javascript file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928827/access-php-var-from-external-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may adopt one of 2 Possibilities... **Option Nr. 1**: You can expose the Number of Images as a Global Variable & Use it in your main.js (that is Assuming that main.js was included in the numberOfImages.php Script. **Option Nr. 2** You can use Ajax to do that too:

**OPTION NR. 1**

```
    <?php 
        //FILE =>numberOfImages.php:

        $dir = "/my/directory/";
        $fi = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
        $fileCount = iterator_count($fi);

        // EXPOSE THIS VARIABLE TO JAVASCRIPT AS A GLOBAL VARIABLE..
        //echo $fileCount; 

    ?>
        // SOMEWHERE IN THE SAME FILE: numberOfImages.php:
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var _NUM_IMAGES = "<?php echo $fileCount; ?>"; 
        </script>
```

Now, you can access the Number of Images in the main.js by simply referencing the variable **_NUM_IMAGES**. So doing alert(__NUM_IMAGES) would work. However, ***be Sure that the main.js is included in the numberOfImages.php File***

**OPTION NR 2**

```
    // INSIDE YOUR HTML/PHP FILE THAT RUNS THE SHOW; IMPORT BOTH JQUERY & YOUR main.js BELOW. 
    // INCLUDE JQUERY LIBRARY: OTHERWISE THIS WON'T WORK...
    // SURE YOU CAN ALSO DO ALL THESE IN PURE JAVASCRIPT, BUT WHY RE-INVENT THE WHEEL???
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

        //YOUR main.js COULD LOOK SOMETHING LIKE THIS:::
        jQuery.noConflict();
        (function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'numberOfImages.php',     // <== POINTS TO THE VALID URL OF THE PHP FILE THAT OUTPUTS THE NUMBER OF IMAGES...
                    dataType: "HTML",
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",

                    //HANDLE THE SUCCESS CASE FOR THE AJAX CALL
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if(data){
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    },

                    //HANDLE THE FAILURE CASE FOR THE AJAX CALL
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
                    },

                    //HANDLE THE EVENT-COMPLETE CASE FOR THE AJAX CALL
                    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

And the numberOfImages.php could look something like this. Exactly the same way you did it:

```
        <?php

            /**
             * filename: numberOfImages.php
             */

            $dir        = "/my/directory/";
            $fi         = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
            $fileCount  = iterator_count($fi);

            die($fileCount);
```

***However, be informed that You need JQuery for this to work. You can add this to the File in which you are importing the main.js but before you import the main.js.***

Comment: My JS file is an external file.

Comment: OK... But is it in any way connected with numberOfImages.php? I mean are you using it in that PHP File?

Comment: No, it is not connected in any way.

Comment: Then Ajax is what you need... because ***Option Nr. 1 won't work in that case*** ...

Comment: Yes, can you please edit your answer accordingly. Thanks you :)

Comment: @Han I already did... and there is now the 2nd Option... hope it does what you want... :-) Cheers...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111928/discussion-between-han-and-poiz).

Answer (score 0):

if your other javascript isn't from an external source you can do something like:

```
<?php
$dir = "/my/directory/";
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$fileCount = iterator_count($fi);
?> 



<script type="text/javascript">var fileCount = "<?= $fileCount?>";</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

    and then in the main.js use FileCount like so:

    alert("fileCount: " + fileCount);
```

Comment: My JS file is from an external source